# BroadcastReceiver Security Issue

Tags: android-security

Issue : Broadcast Receiver (com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver) is Protected by a permission, but the protection level of the permission should be checked.
Permission: com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND [android:exported=true]

Description : A Broadcast Receiver is found to be shared with other apps on the device therefore leaving it accessible to any other application on the device. It is protected by a permission which is not defined in the analysed application. As a result, the protection level of the permission should be checked where it is defined. If it is set to normal or dangerous, a malicious application can request and obtain the permission and interact with the component. If it is set to signature, only applications signed with the same certificate can obtain the permission.

I can only see the permission level and exported parameter for this receiver in my merge Manifest. What do I have to do for this issue ?

Best wishes

Comment: I have the same question following a fortify scan. Did you find out the answer?